# SystemError: error return without exception set, when using requests and debugger

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, pycharm

Environment:
Python 3.6.3
Requests 2.18.4
PyCharm 2018.1

When using the above configuration in normal run everything is fine. However,when using PyCharm debugger my output is constantly giving me two kinds of exceptions:

```
Exception ignored in: <generator object urlsplit.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f69803940a0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/parse.py", line 433, in <genexpr>
    if not rest or any(c not in '0123456789' for c in rest):
```

or

```
SystemError: error return without exception set
Exception ignored in: <generator object iter_slices at 0x7f69803940f8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/damian/workspace/DofusV2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 449, in iter_slices
    def iter_slices(string, slice_length):
`
```

This is not an issue in a single project, I had this issue  in numerous projects countless times. However, every project was multi-threaded ( I do not know if this makes any difference) 
The thing is I do not have this problem when not using the debugger plus it doesn't really do anything the application is stable and works fine. My question is why is this happening and can I at least suppress it so it won't pollute my log?

Comment: Does something  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036540/what-type-of-message-exception-ignored-in-is) help?

Comment: Not really, it only states that the problem maybe due to generator object being destroyed, does not say how to resolve the issue. Plus my problem only occurs when using debugger.

Comment: Yes, the question (and the linked one) to propose solutions. Don't raise Exceptions while Generator cleanup. We can not help you if you don't give code. I thing it only occurs while debugging because the debugger makes more explicit cleanup.

Comment: That could be it, did not think that debugger could work like this. However, as you can see the error occurs in library files which I do not control, so I cannot change that behavior plus I do not know which lines from the project would be relevant to the issue as this is all the traceback info I've got.

Comment: same problem, but the code runs perfectly..

Comment: Same problem here as well, I just updated PyCharm to 2018.1 and python to 3.7, before I used the debugger in the same project many many times and never got this error, while now I keep getting it no matter what I type in the debugger console. I think it might be a bug with the latest PyCharm version

Comment: I posted the problem on the PyCharm issue tracker and they are looking into it

Comment: Just chiming in to say I had this problem also (posted about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48410264/pycharm-debug-mode-throws-fake-errors-but-runs-normally-when-not-in-debug). I didn't find a solution other than rolling back my PyCharm version. Note I am using Python 2.7 though, not 3.x

Comment: Same here, working with Django server and Python 3.6, I get the same error only in debug mode, the proposed solution did not work for me

Answer (score 77):

I had a similar problem when using Gensim Word2vec models, also using debugger in Python 3.6 / PyCharm 2018.2.
Just as a quick fix, I found a solution by setting an environment variable:

```
PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL=NO
```

This can be done easily in PyCharm by settings environment variables in PyCharm run configuration. After setting this variable, I could use debugger again. More info can be found [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/8737) and [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30036).

Comment: The guys at jetbtains suggested the same fix but it did not work for me

Comment: Worked for me pretty well, I set it up in Debug configuration environment variables

Comment: Worked for me as well (Python 3.7; PyCharm 2019.1.2 CE)

Comment: Worked also in `PyCharm 2019 1.2 Ultimate` . Is it possible to add that to env var's for _all_ run configurations by default?

Comment: I guess you can, you can just set environment variables (also outside of PyCharm).

Comment: @javadba You can set it for your entire project using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538859/pycharm-set-environment-variable-for-run-manage-py-task/22899916#22899916

Comment: Worked great. Python 3.7, PyCharm 2018.3 Pro. Thank you!

Comment: I had to set this in the run configuration menu rather than the settings configuration using Pycharm 2018.

Comment: perfect, I can use debug after 7 months use normal run. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps other googlers, in Pycharm 2019 I found I'd caused this error by using a line in my `urlpatterns`:

```
# including this line caused the error (I wanted to catch the 'my_special_model' type and use the general one below for other models.  
    path('display/my_special_model/<int:item_id>/', views.display_model, name='display_model'),

# This works fine ... 
    path('display/<item_type>/<int:item_id>/', views.display, name='display'),
```